# How long does it take for a new plugin to be approved?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, directory, wordpress.org

I've just submited my first wp plugin and i would like to know after how much time will my plugin be published to the wordpress plugin directory?

Hou much did you actually waited?

Comment: I submitted and got response within 5 hours once, had to fix something. I doubt there is a hard answer, as it must be peer reviewed before approval. I would say you probably won't have to wait longer than 24 hours. Hopefully 8 or less.

Comment: It will takes as much time as needed to review your plugin and there is not a fixed delay.

Answer (score 2):

The current procedure is for plugin's code to be reviewed for approval:

- what you can do is to make sure you provided complete and working code
- what you can hope for, is that reviewers (unpaid volunteer reviewers by the way) are not busy with something else at the moment

So essentially it is as long as it takes.

Pro tip - plugins from known (in a *good* way :) developers tend to be approved very fast and with less (to none) scrutiny.

Comment: Famous developers, as opposed to infamous ones

Comment: @GhostToast well.. that's not right..

Answer (score 0):

Actually i've got this email:

(6 hours ago)

> user,
>
> Your plugin hosting request has been approved.
>
> Within one hour, you will have access to your SVN repository at
>
> http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/my-plugin/
>
> with your WordPress.org username and password (the same one you use on
>   the forums).
>
> Here's some handy links to help you get started.
>
> Using Subversion with the WordPress Plugins Directory
>   http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/svn/
>
> FAQ about the WordPress Plugins Directory
>   http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/faq/
>
> WordPress Plugins Directory readme.txt standard
>   http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt
>
> readme.txt validator: http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/validator/
>
> Enjoy!